# Get first and last value for a sequence of pairs between two columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns `Replaced_ID`, `New_ID` and `Installation Date` of `New_ID`.

Each New_ID replaces the Replaced_ID.

```
Replaced_ID      New_ID             Installation Date (of New_ID)
     3             5                    16/02/2018
     5             7                    17/05/2019
     7             9                    21/06/2019
     9             11                   23/08/2020
    25             39                   16/02/2017
    39             41                   16/08/2018
```

My **goal** is to get a dataframe which includes the **first** and **last** record of the sequence. I care only for the first Replaced_ID value and the last New_ID value.

i.e from above dataframe I want this

```
    Replaced_ID      New_ID             Installation Date (of New_ID)
        3              11                    23/08/2020
        25             41                    16/08/2018
```

Sorting by date and perform shift is not the solution here as far as I can imagine.

Also, I tried to join the columns `New_ID` with `Replaced_ID` but this is not the case because it returns only the previous sequence.

I need to find a way to get the sequence `[3,5,7,9,11]` & `[25,41]` combining the `Replaced_ID` & `New_ID` columns for all rows.

I care mostly about getting the first `Replaced_ID` value and the last `New_ID` value and not the `Installation Date` because I can perform join in the end.

Any ideas here? Thanks.

Comment: Merge the intervals on `Replaced_ID` and `New_ID`, and then map the results of `New_ID` to the installation date.

Comment: What do you mean by merging the intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's create the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data = """Replaced_ID,New_ID,Installation Date (of New_ID)
3,5,16/02/2018
5,7,17/05/2019
7,9,21/06/2019
9,11,23/08/2020
25,39,16/02/2017
39,41,16/08/2018
11,14,23/09/2020
41,42,23/10/2020
"""
### note that I've added two rows to check whether it works with non-consecutive rows

### defining some short hands
r = "Replaced_ID"
n = "New_ID"
i = "Installation Date (of New_ID)"

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),header=0,parse_dates=True,sep=",")
df[i] =  pd.to_datetime(df[i], )
```

And now for my actual solution:

```
a = df[[r,n]].values.flatten()
### returns a flat list of r and n values which clearly show duplicate entries, i.e.:
#  [ 3  5  5  7  7  9  9 11 25 39 39 41 11 14 41 42]

### now only get values that occur once, 
#   and reshape them nicely, such that the first column gives the lowest (replaced) id,
#   and the second column gives the highest (new) id, i.e.:
#    [[ 3 14]
#     [25 42]]
u, c = np.unique( a, return_counts=True)
res = u[c == 1].reshape(2,-1)

### now filter the dataframe where "New_ID" is equal to the second column of res, i.e. [14,42]:
#   and replace the entries in "r" with the "lowest possible values" of r
dfn = df[  df[n].isin(res[:,1].tolist()) ]
# print(dfn)
dfn.loc[:][r] = res[:,0]
print(dfn)
```

Which yields:

```
   Replaced_ID  New_ID Installation Date (of New_ID)
6            3      14                    2020-09-23
7           25      42                    2020-10-23
```

Comment: This solution works here because the maximum id per sequence is smaller than the minimum of the next sequence. Here, `u, c = np.unique( a, return_counts=True)` does the sorting job.  If you replace id values 11 with 100, the output should be false. Despite the fact that I need the solution as i describe here (11 replaced from 100, i will mark @Asmus answer as **Correct** because it solves the problem i described. I am now thinking of how to overcome this specific cases. The generated New IDs are greater than the Replaced_IDs from other sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dates are sorted , You can create a helper series and then groupby and aggregate:

```
df['Installation Date (of New_ID)']=pd.to_datetime(df['Installation Date (of New_ID)'])

s = df['Replaced_ID'].ne(df['New_ID'].shift()).cumsum()
out = df.groupby(s).agg(
      {"Replaced_ID":"first","New_ID":"last","Installation Date (of New_ID)":"last"}
     )
```

---

```
print(out)

   Replaced_ID  New_ID Installation Date (of New_ID)
1            3      11                    2020-08-23
2           25      41                    2018-08-16
```

The helper series `s` helps in differentiating the groups by comparing the `Replaced_ID` with the next value of `New_ID` and when they do not match , it returns True. Then with the help of [`series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) we return a sum across the series to create seperate groups:

```
print(s)

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After trying this, I noticed 2 things (after sorting the dates): 1) the dataframe out contains only the rows as is. It does not return the starting Replaced_ID and final New_ID values. 2) the dataframe out contains all the in-between rows. Regarding my example the dataframe out contains rows for the Replaced_ID 5 and Replaced_ID 7.

Note that sorting by date does not mean that rows will refer to the same sequence of pairs.

As a result, s will return True for almost all of the rows.